# How to set a buttons in splash screen , in Android or IOS?

Tags: android, ios, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I need to create a splash screen with buttons or custom div/images with click listener . But how is this possible in Titanium . Or how is this possible in Android or IOS  app .

Also this buttons will be displayed on the first time only .

Any help .
thanks

Comment: Android titanium and ios are 3 totally different things, don't fully understand what you want to do :/ in android use a Button in ios use a NSButton...

Comment: Splash screens are meant for only one purpose, its display something static prior to the launch of app's first screen/window. So splash screens  are meant to be static without having buttons/etc.

Comment: you can try this: First put a black splash screen, then open your custom splashView on opening the app with your button.

Comment: One of the techniques was to have a splash screen and a window/view with exactly the same image.  On the window/view, you have the buttons that take the actions that you want.  This would be the same thing as your index controller in an alloy project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

1.`shared preference`
or
2. `Database`

When the app starts at the first time show the buttons and update the status in the shared preference. Then next time open the app and check first time or not if this is not first time then set the visibility `INVISIBLE` or `GONE`.

And the another one important thing. If you set the time for splash screen with button it leads you the wrong way so handle it carefully.

You can do the same thing with database.
So you can choose shared preference or database.

Note: This is for Android app